# How i can handle a IntetFilter(Android) on Net MAUI?

Tags: android, .net-maui

how i can handle an intent Filter?

i have this annotation under /Plataform/Android/MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend },
          Categories = new[] {
            Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault
          },
          DataMimeType = "*/*")]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
/// --code?
}


///MainPage.xaml.cs 



public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count++;

        if (count == 1)
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
        else
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

        SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
    }

    private void btnDemo_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new DemoPage());

    }
}
```

this hable me to share content from Youtube (example) and Net MAUI Android, but i dont know how to handle the content received into MainPage outside of Android Activity, how i can handle this behavior?
i read about override `OnNewIntent`, invoke method or inject a service but im totally lost

Comment: have you found a solution for this?